# preciso fazer uma função semelhante a uma busca em uma agenda

Tags: python-3.x, for

Fazer uma função que dado como entrada uma lista com informações de contatos e uma string, se a string estiver na lista, deve retornar as informações do contato ou contatos.

- Dentro da lista de entrada, tem listas com as informações dos contatos(nome,telefone(s),e-mail e Instagram).
- a saída deve ser uma lista com as informações do(s) contato(s)
- A string pode ser em maiúsculo e minúsculo

exemplo:

```
entrada([[’Juan Silva’,[’2199112233’, ’2133992211’], 
          ’juanc91@emailquente.com.br’, ’@juansilva91’],
         [’maria Leticia’,[’2198145233’], ”, ’@maria.leticia’],
         ['Daniela Silva',['23456677'], 
         'danisilva@gmail.com','@danisilva']],'silv')
```

Como a string da entrada é 'silv', a saida deve retornar as informações dos contatos que tem silv no nome(como se fosse uma busca na agenda do celular)

```
    saida[[’Juan Silva’,[’2199112233’, ’2133992211’], 
           ’juanc91@emailquente.com.br’, ’@juansilva91’],
          ['Daniela Silva',['23456677'],
           'danisilva@gmail.com','@danisilva']]
```

estou tentando com esse código mas está retornando um erro

```
    def teste(lista_contatos,string):
        soma=0
        for c in lista_contatos[0]:
            if string in lista_contatos[0]:
                soma=soma+lista_contatos[0]
        return soma
```

Comment: Se a saída deve ser uma lista, porque tem `soma = 0` e no final você retorna a soma?

Comment: Outro detalhe é que talvez usar listas não seja a melhor forma de organizar os dados. Provavelmente um dicionário ou uma [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) seja mais adequado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá João você cometeu alguns erros no entendimento da estrutura de dados e em como realizar o retorno destes dados

```
def busca_contato(lista_contatos, nome_pesquisa):
    contatos = list()
    for contato in lista_contatos:
        for dado_contato in contato:
            if nome_pesquisa in dado_contato:
                contatos.append(contato)
                break

    return contatos


lista_contato = [["Juan Silva",["2199112233", "2133992211"], "juanc91@emailquente.com.br", "@juansilva91"], ["maria Leticia",["2198145233"], "@maria.leticia"],['Daniela Silva',['23456677'],'danisilva@gmail.com','@danisilva']]


print(busca_contato(lista_contato,"silv"))
```